# Retrieve external song from own server

Tags: spotify

I am developing a local Spotify application and want to play a my own recorded songs from my external server.

I have tried using:

```
    var single_track = models.Track.fromURI('http://<myserver>/recording.mp3');
```

But I get following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid track URI: http://<myserver>/recording.mp3
```

Is this possible at all? Or is there an alternative way to play songs from my server in spotify (local app)?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. For that specific method you can only use Spotify URIs in the form spotify:track:XXXXXX which identify tracks in Spotify's catalog.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

But is there another way to do this? With Ajax or any other kind of technology? Does anyone have another suggestion to how to be able to play external sound-files?